# Show this quadratic is convex

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I want to show that the following function is convex **without** using the Hessian-based definition of convex.

$$
f(x) = \| x - z \|_2
$$

I believe I am supposed to use this definition:

$$
f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \leq \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y)
$$

Doing so for the function $f(x) = \| x \|_2$ is trivial it seems:
$$
\begin{align*}
\| \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y \|_2 &\leq \| \alpha x \|_2 + \| (1-\alpha) y \|_2 \text{ by triangle inequality} \\
&= \alpha \| x \|_2 + (1-\alpha) \| y \|_2 \text { by homogeneity of } L^2 \text{ norm}
\end{align*}
$$
This satisfies the definition of convex.

When I try to apply this logic to the same function, this is as far as I can get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\| \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y - z \|_2 &\leq \alpha \| x \|_2 + \|(1-\alpha)y - z \|_2
\end{align*}
$$
using the same triangle inequality as above. How do I handle the $-z$ term?

Comment: $$\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y - z = \alpha (x-z) + (1-\alpha)(y-z)$$
A question, though... is $\|\cdot\|_2^2$ or is $\|\cdot\|_2$ your $L^2$-norm?

Comment: I'll mention this to my prof who is using this notation for L2 norm.

Comment: It's not wrong to use a different notation, but it does look awkward to me without more context.  The confusion came from the fact the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is convex, so in either case it's still convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're denoting the $L^2$-norm, you might need to redo the proof for $\|x\|_2^2$ (this looks like the square of the $L^2$-norm to me), but after you have that, the result for the shifted function follows from
$$\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y - z = \alpha(x-z) + (1-\alpha)(y-z)$$